# pagination display when more number of pages

Tags: php, pagination

I am using simple pagination with following code.

But I want to show 1 2 3 ..... 10 11 12 type pagination.

When more number of pages are there, pagination should be adjusted accordingly.

My current simple pagination php code is :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["start"])){
    $start = $db->filter($_GET["start"]);   
}
if(empty($start)){
    $start= 0;
}

$maxrecords = 10;
$pagination_query = "select * from table order by id desc";
$pagination_count = $db->num_rows($pagination_query); 

$query = "select * from table order by id desc limit $start,$maxrecords"; // For record to display...
$result = $db->get_results($query);
?>

<div class="pagination">                            
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<ceil($pagination_count/$maxrecords);$i++){
      if($start==$i*$maxrecords){
?>
<a class='active'> <?php print $i+1;?></a>

<?php }else{ ?>

<a href="?start=<?php print $i*$maxrecords;?>"><?php print $i+1;?></a>
<?php 
  } 
}
?>


</div>                          

 <!-- Rest code to display records goes here -->
```

Now this code is working rightly...

Only thing is it is showing paginatin  - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 like unlimited depending upon total records in database...

I want to convert it to **`1 2 3 .... 22 23 24`** etc...

Your valuable help appreciated...

Comment: As you can see on SO, the pagination looks like, on page 7 : 
`prev  1  …  5  6  [7]  8  9  …  77528  next`. It's a common usage to display *N* pages around the current page, the first and the last. What do you want to display when your current page is **7** ?

Answer (score 2):

My answer begins by some notes about what I'm seeing about pagers.
Then, this answer doesn't provide the "expected result" you want, but I think it could be more "flexible".

1. I think your query to get the number of record seems to be expensive. You could just use a `count(*)` :

   ```
    $pagination_query = "select count(*) as num from table order by id desc" ;
    $pagination_count = $db->get_field_result() ; // I don't know your DB API.
   ```
2. I think your query to get the current results seems to doesn't take care about the `$start` and `$maxrecords` (but I don't known your database API) :

   ```
    $query = "select * from table order by id desc limit ".($start*$maxrecords).",$maxrecords"; // range 0+10, 10+10, 20+10, ...
   ```
3. You could use several loops to display begining pages, "around current", and ending pages.

Here is a "sample" code, **not perfect**, but it could helps you to imaging *your* own pager.

```
$start = 7 ; // try with 1, 7, 24, 75...
$pagination_count = 40 ; // Number of results
$maxrecords = 10 ;

$num_pages = ceil($pagination_count / $maxrecords) ;
// echo "num_pages=$num_pages\n" ; // Just for dev

if ($start > $num_pages) { $start = $num_pages; }

if ($num_pages < 6) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_pages ; $i++) {
        echo render_page_link($i, $start);
    }
}
else {
        
    // Begining
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < min(3, $num_pages); $i++) {
        echo render_page_link($i,$start) ;
    }
    echo ' (...) ' ;
    
    $have_middle = ($start > 3 && $start <= $num_pages - 3) ;
    if ($have_middle) {
        // Around current
        for ($i = max(3, $start - 3); $i < min($start + 3 - 1, $num_pages - 3) ; $i++) {
            echo render_page_link($i,$start) ;
        }
    }
    
    // Ending
    if ($have_middle) echo ' (...) ' ;
    for ($i = $num_pages - 3; $i < $num_pages ; $i++) {
        echo render_page_link($i,$start);
    }

}

echo "\n"; // just because I test on CLI.

// Here is a little function to display the link:
// Currently just "plain text", but could be <a> or <span> with CSS...
function render_page_link($index, $current = -1)
{
    if ($index != $current - 1) return ($index+1) . " "  ;
    return "[".($index+1)."] " ;
}
```

**Example result for 1 to 24 pages**

```
[1] 2 3  (...) 22 23 24 
1 [2] 3  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 [3]  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) [4] 5 6  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 4 [5] 6 7  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 4 5 [6] 7 8  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 5 6 [7] 8 9  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 6 7 [8] 9 10  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 7 8 [9] 10 11  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 8 9 [10] 11 12  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 9 10 [11] 12 13  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 10 11 [12] 13 14  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 11 12 [13] 14 15  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 12 13 [14] 15 16  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 13 14 [15] 16 17  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 14 15 [16] 17 18  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 15 16 [17] 18 19  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 16 17 [18] 19 20  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 17 18 [19] 20 21  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 18 19 [20] 21  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 19 20 [21]  (...) 22 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) [22] 23 24 
1 2 3  (...) 22 [23] 24 
1 2 3  (...) 22 23 [24]
```

Comment: what if $num_pages=4 it will print 1 2 3 2 3 4

Comment: @eomer Right. I've edited the answer (see https://3v4l.org/TXAMR).

Comment: btw. I've added 
if ((num_pages - 2) > 4 && start  - 2 > 4) control so that 
[1] 2 3  (...) 4 5 6 will be 1 2 3 4 5 6